# How to place footnotes in the caption of a table?

Tags: tables, captions, footnotes, tabularx

### Problem:

Question title says it all, although it can be misunderstood, what I am trying to achieve is through a command (hoping for `footnote`) to be able to place a footnote mark anywhere in the table and place it in the caption of the table, **not in the bottom of the page**, obviously avoiding repeated footnote marks (off course there will be footnote marks in the bottom of the page, coming from the text), if possible, using the same footnote marks that the `footnote` command is using.

### Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

### MWE:

This minimal working example is made just to ease the need of start a code, however it does not employ the desired technique for the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|l|r}
    \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Zone} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Power Supply} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Phase} \\
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Kind\textsuperscript{*}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{or Area \textsuperscript{$\Psi$}}\\
\hline\hline
A & Single-phase & Machining
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Power requirements.\\\textsuperscript{*}Single or three phase.\\\textsuperscript{$\Psi$} Important note.}
  \label{tab:phaseDistribution}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Obtained through code]

How can this be done?

Comment: Take a look at `threeparttable` and/or `threeparttablex`. But it is not recommended to use the same series of markers as are used for regular footnotes. (None of this puts footnotes in the caption, but you don't really seem to want that.) The footnotes are actually part of the table. They should be under the table and before the caption, which describes the whole table.

Comment: @cfr's comment is by far the best answer (I combine `threeparttable` with `multicol` as my table notes tend to be short).  I did use the same set of symbols (letters) for both in my thesis, but I had ~10 footnotes in >200 pages, none of which were on the same page as tables (and my tables were always at the bottom).  I also used numeric-superscript citaions so they weren't available for footnotes.

Answer (score 3):

So, there is a [tablefootnote package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote?lang=de). However, it places the description of the footnote somewhere in the text in the same numeration as for normal footnotes. There may be a possibility to change this, but there is another possibility, which I would prefer.

With the [threeparttable package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) you can insert modified footnotes and list them where you want. In my case, I like to list them below the table, as the caption is placed above (captions for tables above, captions for figures below).

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{This is a caption}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
1&This is a line without footnote\\
2&This is a line with a footnote \tnote{\dag}\\
3&This is a line with another footnote\tnote{\ddag}\\
4&This is a line with the same footnote as in line 2\tnote{\dag}\\
5&This is a line with a third footnote\tnote{+}\\
\end{tabular}
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[\dag] Footnote from line 2 and 4
\item[\ddag] Footnote from line 3
\item[+] Footnote from line 5
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This gives you this table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not so good at Latex, but this is how I solved my problem: add the footnotes as multicolumns at the end of the tabular environment. Use the font size of your preference there.  Taking you example, I added the footnotes as shown below. Hope it helps

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|l|r}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Zone} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Power Supply} &     \multicolumn{1}{c}{Phase} \\
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Kind\textsuperscript{*}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{or Area         \textsuperscript{$\Psi$}}\\\hline\hline
A & Single-phase & Machining\\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize * Single or three phase.}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize  {$\Psi$} Important note.}
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Power requirements.}
  \label{tab:phaseDistribution}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```